# How to send multipart data in POST Request Hikvision ISAPI

Tags: api, multipart, hikvision

I am trying to send a picture to a `DS-K1T671M Facial Recognition Device from Hikvision` using `Hikvision ISAPI`.

The documentation says that I need to call

```
POST /ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json

body:

{
  "faceLibType": "blackFD",
  "FDID": "1",
  "FPID": "1"
}
```

It says I need to send this body + a binary picture. Therefore I will need to send multipart data (The picture + the JSON content).

**1º REQUEST**

Therefore, in Postman if I send this request in the picture.

[image]

It gives me an error because I didn't set up my json body data too.

**2º REQUEST**

Then, I tried to send it using multipart.

[image]

It has the file and the JSON but still didn't work.

**SAMPLES FROM DOCUMENTATION**

I'll post the request from the documentation

```
Example
Add Face Record When Binary Picture is Uploaded in Form Format
1) POST /ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json
2) Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml,
3) Accept-Language: us-EN
4) Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=-------------------7e
5) User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (cŽmƉĂtibůĞ͖ MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
6) Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
7) Host: 10.10.36.29:8080
8) Content-Length: 9907
9) Connection: Keep-Alive
10) Cache-Control: no-cache
11)
12) -----------------------------7e13971310878
13) Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FaceDataRecord";
14) Content-Type: application/json
15) Content-Length: 9907
16)
17) {
a) "faceLibType": "blackFD",
b) "FDID": "1223344455566788",
c) "FPID": "11111aa"
18) }
19) -----------------------------7e13971310878
20) Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FaceImage";
21) Content-Type: image/jpeg
22) Content-Length: 9907
23)
24) ......JFIF.....`.`.....C........... .
25) ..
26) ................. $.' ",#..(7),01444.'9=82<.342...C. ....
27) -----------------------------7e13971310878--
```

They have a working sample in C#

```
{
  szUrl = "/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json";

  if (!szUrl.Substring(0, 4).Equals("http"))
  {
    szUrl = "http://" + AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strDeviceIP + ":" + AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strHttpPort + szUrl;
  }
  HttpClient clHttpClient = new HttpClient();
  szResponse = string.Empty;
  szRequest = "{\"faceLibType\":\"" + comboBoxFaceType.SelectedItem.ToString() +
    "\",\"FDID\":\""+textBoxFDID.Text+
    "\",\"FPID\":\""+textBoxEmployeeNo.Text+"\"}";
  string filePath = textBoxFilePath.Text;
  szResponse = clHttpClient.HttpPostData(AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strUsername, AddDevice.struDeviceInfo.strPassword, szUrl, filePath, szRequest);
  ResponseStatus res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseStatus>(szResponse);
    if (res!=null && res.statusCode.Equals("1"))
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Set Picture Succ!");
        return;
      }
      MessageBox.Show("Set Picture Failed!");
}
```

```
public string HttpPostData(string strUserName, string strPassword, string url,
            string filePath, string request)
        {
            string responseContent = string.Empty;
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // 边界符  
            var boundary = "---------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            // 边界符  
            var beginBoundary = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            // 最后的结束符  
            var endBoundary = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

            // 设置属性  
            webRequest.Credentials = GetCredentialCache(url, strUserName, strPassword);
            webRequest.Timeout = m_iHttpTimeOut;
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml,";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN");
            webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            //写入JSON报文
            string header =
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"FaceDataRecord\";\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: "+request.Length+"\r\n\r\n";
            var headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
            memStream.Write(beginBoundary, 0, beginBoundary.Length);
            memStream.Write(headerBytes,0,headerBytes.Length);
            memStream.Write(requestBytes,0,requestBytes.Length);

            var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];

            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fileStream.Close();

            // 写入文件  
            header = "\r\n--"+boundary+"\r\n"+
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"FaceImage\";\r\n" +
                 "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"+
                 "Content-Length: " +buffer.Length+"\r\n\r\n";
            headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

            memStream.Write(headerBytes, 0, headerBytes.Length);
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var contentLine = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n");
            memStream.Write(contentLine, 0, contentLine.Length);

            // 写入最后的结束边界符  
            memStream.Write(endBoundary, 0, endBoundary.Length);

            webRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

            var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

            memStream.Position = 0;
            var tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            memStream.Close();

            requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            try
            {
                var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

                using (var httpStreamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(),
                                                                Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
                {
                    responseContent = httpStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                httpWebResponse.Close();
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            fileStream.Close();
            
            webRequest.Abort();

            return responseContent;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I gave up trying that way. I do it now with faceURL.

```json
{
  "faceLibType": "blackFD",
  "FDID": "1",
  "FPID": "9",
  "faceURL": "https://192.168.0.128:3000/avatar/11aa3bc9b410187df1907ad4092eedb3.jpg"
}
```

Comment: same here, I try so hard to do it by the multipart way but it's seems to be imposible. Using the faceURL its the better way but if your url have CORS or some security level can be a little tricky to

Answer (score 1):

I think the maximum size of image which can store is 200kb as notice in web admin of camera.
So can not add image more than it.
Admin page: http://192.168.1.230/#/home/peopleManage
Notice: "The picture format should be JPEG and the size should be less than 200 K."
Or you can view this quesion:

[How to create multipart/form-data which contains json and binary image data, then serialize it and pass it to IntPtr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558295/how-to-create-multipart-form-data-which-contains-json-and-binary-image-data-the/67715565#67715565)

thanks